# p5.js: How would I make the player move continuously?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am creating a game, but I have an issue where i want to move the player left or right but when I press the button it only moves it left or right once and not continuously

```
var player 1 = new Player(width / 4)

function keyPressed() {
    if (key === "d") {
        player1.move(1);
      } else if (key === "a") {
        player1.move(-1);
      }
   }



function Player(xPos) {
  this.x = xPos;
  this.y = height - 100;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 100);
  }

  this.move = function(dir) {
    this.x += dir * 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of moving on keypress, set a flag on keypress, and while that flag is active, move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `keyIsDown()` instead of `keyPressed()`.

From the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown):

> The keyIsDown() function checks if the key is currently down, i.e.
>   pressed. It can be used if you have an object that moves, and you want
>   several keys to be able to affect its behaviour simultaneously, such
>   as moving a sprite diagonally. You can put in any number representing
>   the keyCode of the key, or use any of the variable keyCode names
>   listed here.

Should also be inside the `draw()` function:

```
function draw(){
    if(keyIsDown("d")){
        player1.move(1);
    }
    if (keyIsDown("a")) {
        player1.move(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I tried to use this "keyIsDown() in the keyPressed() function, but I didn't realise they done it inside draw(). My mistake, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Eduardas Nice, I edited my answer to include the `draw()` function.